# How can I make sure UUID is unique for my BLE service or characteristic?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to configure a unique 128-bit UUID, help me to find the proper solution to find it.

Comment: Do you mean UUIDs for beacons any other BLE device? OR something else.

Comment: just type `uuidgen` on a unix command line.  The chances of uuid collision are infinitesimally small

Comment: @AshwinIndianic : It is about custom services that i creating for my application

Comment: @Paulw11 : I have multiple services for my app....

Comment: You can either generate multiple UUIDs or just generate one and change the last digit(s) as reqiured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this talk on Unique UUID.

http://www.cypress.com/forum/psoc-4-ble/how-can-i-get-uuid-services-and-characteristics

let me know if any other best and standard way to find UUID